# Deep Fritz 14, Show Plans-How to activate?

Tags: fritz

Does anyone who uses Deep Fritz 14 know how to activate "Visualize Search," aka "Show Plans"? I went to File, Options, and Engine. "Show Plans" is one of the options, but it won't let me activate it. How do you activate it?

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to activate such feature? It's worthless!

Comment: It's not worthless because the computer will show you plans that you probably haven't thought of, and by studying its plans, you can understand them.

Comment: But chess analysis is not about someone telling you what you have to do, but rather about exploring it yourself

Comment: @David I would disagree. It can be a good idea to see what the best move/plans are so that you can identify them more consistently in the future. When you play, it's about exploring things yourself, but when you analyze, you look to an external source to determine what went right and what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be for future use: Although it is two versions later, to quote the Fritz 16 online manual: "Show Plans - Displays the planned Manoeuver of the engine. The function is not supported by any engine!"

[Fritz 16 Manual](http://help.chessbase.com/Fritz/16/Eng/index.html?options___engine.htm)

Comment: You told me that it appears to be for future use. Does that mean that Fritz 16 is the only version that supports this?

Comment: At least per the current manual, I am saying that even as of Fritz 16, they still have not implemented it.